# Core Data: Constraints are conflicting even after deleting all data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, ios10

**Constraints are conflicting even after deleting all data.**

I added `unique id constraint` for my entities in core data.

It works fine  if app is newly installed & insert data.

but when I try to insert more data after sometime then it is not inserted.

I also tried with delete all data from db &re-insert new one, but still not working.

**MY try**

```
 func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy //May be this creating problem
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                    }
      }

func DeleteAllData() {


        for entity in ["entity1","entity2","entity3"] {

            // Create Fetch Request
             let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)

            // Create Batch Delete Request
            let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

            do {
                try appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
            } catch {
                // Error Handling
            }
        }
    }
```

**Thanks for your time**

Comment: You should look at errors sent by Core Data. How can you debug this if you don't catch any errors ?

Comment: @McNight,
if i removed `mergepolicy` then app is showing error of constraint in `catch` block. 

**error**  Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x608000468600) for constraint (\n    id\n)